# Why does the below code not discount any with amount below 9.99

Tags: postgresql

The below code does not follow the subquery as I am looking to see the people with amount above 9.99.

```
select customer_id,first_name
from customer
join payment using (customer_id)
where customer_id in(select customer_id from payment where amount > 9.99)
order by customer_id
```

If I do not use join payment using (customer_id) then it works but I want to see amount which is only in the payment table.

Answer (score 1):

In your current query you do a useless join of `customer` to `payment` because all you need is the `WHERE` clause:

```
select customer_id, first_name
from customer
where customer_id in (select customer_id from payment where amount > 9.99)
order by customer_id
```

If this (like your query) does not return what you need, maybe it is because you want the `customer_id`s of customers who made payments > 9.99 **only**.
 
To get these customers you must modify the subquery after `IN` like this:

```
select customer_id, first_name
from customer
where customer_id in (
  select customer_id 
  from payment 
  group by customer_id
  having min(amount) > 9.99
)
order by customer_id
```

This subquery returns `customer_id`s of customers whose minimum payment is greater than `9.99`.